# jsonrpc4j: Composite streaming client

Tags: java, streaming, client, composite, json-rpc

I'm trying to call a server with composite services, created as shown in the documentation:

```
        Object compositeService = ProxyUtil.createCompositeServiceProxy(
            this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            new Object[] { fileUploadService, remoteCommandService},
            new Class<?>[] { FileUploadService.class, RemoteCommandService.class},
            true);
```

The problem is I don't know how to create a JsonRpcClient to connect the composite server via streaming (socket). I couldn't find any example in the documentation, and all the code I wrote throws some Exception.

Should I use the method ProxyUtil.createClientProxy() ? How can that work if it requires an interface as parameter, while Object is a class?

Any help would be highly appreciated.